# Angular12 How can I set table td content from ts file in custom table component?

Tags: angular

I want to show table th and td content from an Array.

My table works well when I use below code:

```
 <thead>
      <tr>
        <th
        *ngFor="let column of listOfColumns"          
        >
        {{ column.name }}
        </th>

      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr  *ngFor="let data of sourceData">
          <td>
            <a routerLink="/bonusCalculate/employeeInfo/{{data.Pid}}">
                {{ data.Name }}
            </a>
          </td>
          <td>{{ data.Pid }}</td>
        
        </tr>
    </tbody>
```

The problem is that now I want to create a table component and I want to pass th and td content to the component.But it does not work since the `{{ data.Pid }}` is not recognized.What I am trying is using `innerHtml` like below

table.component.ts:

```
listOfColumns: ColumnItem[] = [
{
  name: 'EmployeeName',
  sortOrder: null,
  sortDirections: ['ascend', 'descend', null],
  columnKey: 'Name',
  tdContent:`
    <a routerLink="/employeeInfo/{{data.Pid}}">
        {{ data.Name }}
    </a>
 `
},
{
  name: 'EmployeeId',
  sortOrder: null,
  sortDirections: ['ascend', 'descend', null],
  columnKey: 'pId',
  tdContent:` {{ data.Pid }}`
}
```

];

table.component.html:

```
<thead>
      <tr>
        <th
        *ngFor="let column of listOfColumns"          
        >
        {{ column.name }}
        </th>

      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr  *ngFor="let data of sourceData">
          <td *ngFor="let content of listOfColumns" [innerHtml]="content.tdContent">
           </td>
        
        </tr>
    </tbody>
```

It is incorrect and show `{{data.name}}` as string directly ,but I want to dispaly its real value .
How can I achieve it ?

Comment: The way in which you are try to doing, It will never work!, you have created a separate component for table, & you just want to resume that component with your actual component right? & you are facing the issue that you are not able to  send data for  table `td` & `th`, for that  you have to use `@Input()` decorator! It will resolve your issue

Comment: @Suneel Kumar `th` is correct, what I have error is the `{{data.Pid}}` in td is not parsed.since I want to have custom td content (may have link,image..) so I don't think @Input is helpful（or could you show how to use it?)

Comment: yes I can, but as per my understanding in your case you  just want to add `anchor link` within `td` right?

Comment: @Suneel Kumar yes, and I also have some buttons with (onclick) on them (CRUD)

Comment: please share your source code with this editor https://stackblitz.com/, I will check & provide you proper solution

Comment: @Suneel Kumar there's error in the code but it shows what I want to get .https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-sorrdh?file=src/app/my-table/my-table.component.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Angular text interpolation does not work with innerHtml.**

You can find the valid ways of using Text interpolation in angular over here,
https://angular.io/guide/interpolation

**Template literals** can be used to address your problem of passing dynamic templates to set in innerHtml, .

For example, your tdContent of the column can be converted to a function that return a dynamic html using rowdata and template literal

```
listOfColumns = [
{
  name: 'EmployeeName',
  sortOrder: null,
  sortDirections: ['ascend', 'descend', null],
  columnKey: 'Name',
  tdContent: (rowData)=>
    `<a href="/employeeInfo/${rowData.Pid}">
        ${ rowData.Name }
    </a>
  `
},
{
  name: 'EmployeeId',
  sortOrder: null,
  sortDirections: ['ascend', 'descend', null],
  columnKey: 'pId',
  tdContent:(rowData)=> ` ${rowData.Pid }`
}
]
```

So while setting inner html call this function with rowData as input,

```
<tr *ngFor="let data of sourceData">
      <td *ngFor="let content of listOfColumns" [innerHtml]="content.tdContent(data)">
</td>
```

Please find the working version in stackblitz, https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-rhr6sh

Output,

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much it works in this demo.But if I use `ng-zorro-antd` in my project, I add  nz-button in the `tdContent` it seems not work and the button does not display at all and show as string.Do you have any ideas?

Comment: inner html cannot display components from your angular modules directly, there might be other workarounds

Comment: I agree with you. So I am finding what is the best solution to my requirement. Could you give some advice？Anyway ,thank you very much for this problem

Comment: could not find a straight forward solution, but this may be a starting point, https://www.arka.com/blog/dynamically-generate-angular-components-from-external-html  - But input & output events are not handled here

Answer (score 0):

Angular not "compile" expresions, so you can not use `[innerHtml]="some with an angular directive"`. You can make it using Angular elements (see this [Netanel basal article](https://netbasal.com/render-angular-components-using-plain-text-5a6377125bf3) if you're interested), but it's use a sledgehammer to crack nuts.

You can think in some like

```
listOfColumns: ColumnItem[] = [
{
  name: 'EmployeeName',
  sortOrder: null,
  sortDirections: ['ascend', 'descend', null],
  columnKey: 'Name',
  url:"/employeeInfo/",
  key:"pId"
},
{
  name: 'EmployeeId',
  sortOrder: null,
  sortDirections: ['ascend', 'descend', null],
  columnKey: 'pId'
}
```

And

```
   <tr  *ngFor="let data of sourceData">
      <td *ngFor="let content of listOfColumns">
        <ng-container *ngIf="url">
           <a routerLink="content.url+'/++data[content.key]">
            {{ data[content.columnKey] }}
           </a>
        </ng-container>
        <ng-container *ngIf="!url">
            {{data[content.columnKey]}}
        </ng-container>
       </td>
    </tr>
```

Or create a component that can use like

```
<table-component [dataSource]="datasource" [listOfColumns]="listOfColumns" >
       <tr *ngFor="let data of sourceData">
          <td>
            <a routerLink="/bonusCalculate/employeeInfo/{{data.Pid}}">
                {{ data.Name }}
            </a>
          </td>
          <td>{{ data.Pid }}</td>
        </tr>
</table-component>
```

And you component (with the only logic is sort the table)

```
<table>
   <thead>
      <tr>
        <th *ngFor="let column of listOfColumns">
        {{ column.name }}
        </th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <ng-content>
        </ng-content> 
    </tbody>
```

Comment: Thank you.Since I am writing a common table component with `ng-zorro-antd`,i can not ensure that it only has a link or some buttons or an image in one td,so the first way seems not good.The second way is what I already use ,and i want to know whether it is meaningless to do like this(it seems that the second way does not reduce code in html than not using the custom component)